# Can wifi and 3G work at the same time on Android?

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I am doing a project which needs the Android tablet to communicate with a local network device via Wifi(tcp/ip) and at the same time send data to server via 3G(http request).

The Android tablet receives data from local network device every 1 seconds. This connection must not be disconnected during the whole running time. And the Android tablet will send data to server using HTTP request some time (every minute or longer interval).

Is it possible to make WIFI and 3G working at the same time? If no, any suggestion for my problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

yes it should work. you can observe this when you are downloading mms, typically even when your wifi is on mms can be downloaded only on 3G or data network.

Comment: Hi, i think you are right.But my question is making both of them working at the same time. WIFI will perform data communication every 1 second and 3G did in longer interval. No switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

I developed an application which prints on W-lan printers and also send and get data over 3G, so i would say yes. But if you are sufing with your phone it will prefer w-lan and use only one of them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.But how do you do that in your app? Do you actually use WIF(TCP/IP Socket) and 3G(HTTP) at the same time like me?

Comment: Yes i send data over 3G to a server and printing over W-Lan at the same time. The connection over WiFi commes with the sdk of the printer i just use a connect function which needs the ip and the portm if you need more information about that, let me know :-)